# Problems with react-static-google-map

Tags: typescript

I've installed latest version of `react-static-google-map`. Currently I am using typescript version 3.0 but I got the following errors:

```
node_modules/react-static-google-map/typings/index.d.ts:166:3 - error TS1038: A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.

166   declare const MarkerGroupComponent: StatelessComponent<MarkerGroup>;
      ~~~~~~~

node_modules/react-static-google-map/typings/index.d.ts:195:3 - error TS1038: A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.

195   declare const PathGroupComponent: StatelessComponent<PathGroup>;
      ~~~~~~~
```

In my `tsconfig.json` I've ignored `node_modules`

```
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
]
```

how to avoid this checking?

I've checked: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-file-in-the-exclude-list-still-picked-up-by-the-compiler

but without success.

**EDIT:** One possible solution is adding `--skipLibCheck` to typescript compiler, but I don't want to loose type-safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import anything from `react-static-google-map`, then TypeScript automatically loads the typings file specified in `node_modules/react-static-google-map/package.json` (which is `node_modules/react-static-google-map/typings/index.d.ts`) so it can give you type information.  The typings file is wrong: those extra `declare` keywords should be removed.  Consider submitting a PR to [the repository](https://github.com/bondz/react-static-google-map).  In the meantime, your best option is probably to add a modified version of the `react-static-google-map` package to your project and register it in your `package.json` dependencies using a local path.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The implementation of static maps is pretty straightforward, but the api looked nice. I guess I'll submit the PR. Btw, thanks for the explanation, I was considering when you do `exclude` on `tsconfig` then everything on `node_modules` should be ignored, but it is not because of the import.